# Use variable and filter within tag in nunjucks + eleventy

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

I am a nunjucks newbie - trying it out along with eleventy.

**Short version:** can I use variables and filters within tags in nunjucks? For example:

{% set myVar = {{ title | lower }} %}

(assume the {{ title }} variable is set correctly)

**Longer version / my specific use case:**

I am trying to create a layout file called section.njk and use it for several pages (basically the section frontpages of each section of my site - similar idea to a section.html layout file in Hugo) I have a data file for each section, containing the menu for that section.

Given the following files:

- guides.json
- index.md with frontmatter including title: "Guides"

This does not work:

```
{% for item in {{ title | lower }} %}
<a href="{{ item.url | url }}"><div>{{ item.title }}</div></a>
{% endfor %}
```

This works:

```
{% for item in guides %}
<a href="{{ item.url | url }}"><div>{{ item.title }}</div></a>
{% endfor %}
```

So I'm wondering if the problem is using variables within tags in Nunjucks, and if so, if there's a way round it?

Entire project source is here: https://github.com/StarfallProjects/tech-writer-toolkit/tree/11ty  (the 11ty stuff is in src)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

```
{% set myVar = title | lower  %}
{% set myVar = title | lower + var2 | upper %}
{% set myVar = (title | lower  + var2) | trim %}
...
{% for item in items | sort(false, true)  %}
<a href="{{ item.url | url }}"><div>{{ item.title | lower}}</div></a>
{% endfor %}
```

The `lower`, `upper` and `trim` filters are applyed to number/string vars. They can't be applyed for some array (or object).
On the another side, the `sort`-filter expects an array as input.

The filter "type" is obvious by its description in [docs](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#sort-arr-reverse-casesens-attr).

Comment: Thank you! Setting a variable as you describe worked, but weirdly your response to my specific case {% for item in title | lower %} didn't. I wonder if this is an eleventy thing - maybe it has to have a string rather than a variable to go looking for the data file or something?

Comment: This also didn't work: {% set myVar = title | lower %}
{{ myVar }}

{% for item in myVar %}
<a href="{{ item.url | url }}"><div>{{ item.title }}</div></a>
{% endfor %}